# Output to Pipeline from within IF ELSE statement

Tags: powershell, csv, conditional-statements, pipeline

**UPDATE: I just found out that the client I am running this on is PS V1. I can't use splatting.**

I have a script for processing csv files. I don't know ahead of time if the file will have a header or not so I'm prompting the user to either input a header or use the one in the file:

```
$header = Read-Host 'Input your own header?'
```

What I want to do is be able to check whether the header variable has been set to decide if I want to use that flag when executing the Import-CSV commandlet.

I have tried a number of things along the lines of:

```
IF($Header){Import-Csv $File -delimiter $delimiter -Header $header }
ELSE 
{Import-Csv $File -delimiter $delimiter} |
```

Or

```
IF($Header){Import-Csv $File -delimiter $delimiter -Header $header | %{$_} }
ELSE 
{Import-Csv $File -delimiter $delimiter | %{$_}}
```

The first example results in complaints of an empty pipeline. The second results in the first column of the file just being ouptut to the console and then errors when the file is done processing because the rest of the pipeline is empty.

As always any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: In your first example, the empty pipeline error is being caused by that extra pipe at the end of your Else clause.

Comment: I think the thought was that IF/ELSE statements could feed into a pipeline. They can't just like a foreach() {} can't feed into a pipeline.  They are statements and not expressions.  They can be turned into expressions by putting them in a sub-expression using `$()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is just to use the `-OutVariable` option on Import-Csv

`Import-Csv -Path:$File -Delimiter:$Delimiter -OutVariable:CSVContents` will save it in `$CSVContents`

From the Import-CSV Technet page:

This cmdlet supports the common parameters: -Verbose, -Debug, -ErrorAction, -ErrorVariable, -OutBuffer, and -OutVariable. For more information, see  about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=113216).

Another alternative is to use an args hash and "splat" it:

```
$myArgs = @{
    Path = "$HOME\temp\foo"
}

Get-Content @myArgs
```

Update for Version 1 (untested):

```
( IF($Header) { Import-Csv $File -delimiter $delimiter -Header $header }
  ELSE { Import-Csv $File -delimiter $delimiter} ) |
#More pipeline commands here, example:
Format-Table
```

Horrible disgusting version (untested):

```
$ImportCommand = "Import-Csv $File -delimiter $delimiter"
If($header -ne $null) { $ImportCommand += " -header $header" }
Invoke-Expression $ImportCommand | 
Format-Table
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This was absolutely helpful because I didn't know you could pass a parameters variable to commandlets.

Comment: This is still helpful, but I can't use splatting because this machine is using PS V1

Comment: I actually have tested the first V1 suggestion before posting this question and it didn't work either. I suspect it is evaluating the expression and then not passing anything to the pipeline. The second example I gave was an attempt to force PS to pass something on as it evaluated. I will test the second version. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Option 2 in your updated suggestions worked. I just had to be careful.

The Delimiter variable now needs to include the quotes in the string. Do $delimiter = "|" becomes $delimiter = '"|"'

Also, Read-Host seems to return an empty string if nothing is entered into the text box, so If($header -ne $NULL) becomes If($header -ne '')

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, all kinds of security issues can crop up when trusting user input.

Answer (score 4):

Eris already suggested splatting, but I wanted to give a more comprehensive example, using your code.

```
# Declare a hash containing the parameters you will always need 
$csvParams = @{
    File = $File;
    delimiter = $delimiter;
}

# if the header is specified, add a Header to $csvParams
if ($Header) { $csvParams.Header = $header }

# Call Import-Csv, splatting $csvParams
Import-Csv @csvParams
```

Splatting is an extremely useful technique. Get-Help about_Splatting for more information about it.

Comment: Thanks for this Kevin. I'm marking yours as the answer because it gave a clear demo of how to conditionally add parameters to the $params variable.

Comment: Hey man, just found out I'm using PS V1. I can't use splatting so I will have to un-accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You second approach is the way I would go.  I'm not sure why, what you have shown for your second example, would be failing.  Here is what I would do:

```
filter ProcessCsv {
    $_ | ... further processing ...
}

$header = Read-Host 'Input your own header?'
if ($header) {
    Import-Csv $file -Delimiter $delimiter -Header $header | ProcessCsv
else {
    Import-Csv $file -Delimiter $delimiter | ProcessCsv
}
```

Comment: This will work of course, but I'm trying to avoid storing the entire contents in memory before I can move on to processing. The pipeline approach I'm using is that I can process the file as a stream of line objects.

Comment: No problem just put the processing code in a function or filter as shown in the updated example.

Comment: That updated suggestion using a function is pretty awesome. I have already accepted another suggestion, but I will definitely keep this in my toolbox. Thanks again.

Comment: If you're concerned about not reading the whole CSV into memory then don't use the `-OutVariable` parameter initially suggested in that answer.  :-)